# Is there a way to "pin" an open folder to the Mac desktop

Tags: macos, mac, desktop-customization, user-folders

I'm sorry if this question is somewhat convoluted but I'm having trouble putting what I'm looking for into words.  I'm wondering if there is any type of extension / 3rd party tool that allows for folders that live elsewhere within the Mac file system (i.e. not on the Desktop) to be shown / pinned / "glued" open on the mac desktop.

I.e. image you were to open a folder on your Mac from finder, cut out all of the "chrome" navigation, etc from the Finder window leaving you just the stuff inside that folder, and stitch that to your Mac desktop so that it is always open and you always have access to it.

Again, sorry if this sounds crazy, thank you in advance for any help anyone can offer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Your desktop is actually a subdirectory under your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Unix).

Knowing that, you can create a symbolic link to any directory from your `~/Desktop`. For example, open the Terminal.app and type in

```
ln -s /System/Library/LaunchAgents/ ~/Desktop/lagents
```

to get on your Desktop something called "lagents", which works just like any other folder on your Desktop. Except, of course, that what you're really manipulating when opening "lagents" is "/System/Library/LaunchAgents".

Comment: I don't think he's looking for aliases/symbolic links.  His question actually refer to some kind of "folder widget" for the desktop. This being not about a technical issue, I believe it should be moved to Apple stack exange.

Comment: You might be right. The question is more than slightly cryptic, to my feeble English at least.

Comment: @RetroDroid - I'm sorry the question is hard to understand - I'm having trouble describing what I'm looking for BUT I think "folder widget" nails it.  A symbolic link is only 1/2 way to what i'm looking for.  I want the contents of the folder to be visible on the desktop at all times without having to open it.